# Google Website Translator not working for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I am trying to use Google Website Translator in a chrome extension.

However I have not been able to get it working so far within a Chrome extension. Although it works perfectly when used directly in a page but not when doing the same in a chrome extension.

The code snippet is as below

```
j$("body").append("<div id='google_translate_element'></div>
                   <script>
                       function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                           new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout:google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL},'google_translate_element');}
                   </script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit'></script>"
                );
```

The code is added inside jQuery(document).ready(function(){});

What am I missing?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @eddie_cat - Any clues on the question?

Comment: No, sorry. I actually came across your question in the review queue, this is not my personal area of expertise. It might help if you edit your question to explain exactly what is not working. Also include a JavaScript tag as it's relevant and likely more popular than tags relating specifically to translation.